# easy way to multiply a value to successive substrings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, substring, return-value

Good morning, sorry for my poor English.
I'm a neophyte and I'm trying to create a javascript program that, given a string in input, if it finds inside defined substrings it returns a value to each substring and returns the sum of the values ​​found as output. Everything ok here. But I'm finding it difficult to manage the case where in front of the substring that I'm looking for, there's for example "2x" which means that the value of the next substring (or of all subsequent substring) is to be multiplied for 2. How can I write in simple code this exception?

Example:

```
A1 = 1
M1 = 1
input description = A1-M1
output = 2

input descritpion = 2 x A1-M1
output = 4
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If "A1-M1" means "A1 + M1", shouldn't the latter expression be " input description = 2 x (A1-M1)" namely with parentheses?

Comment: no A1-M1 is the string in input. is to be considered as string value = "A1-M1". And I want to search "A1" and "M1" separately.

Comment: That does not clarify it. Anyway, there are numerous Q&A about string evaluation on Stack Overflow. Why is this question different?

Comment: Because I don't find a solution for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

For more comprehesion, you can find my code below:

```
let str_description = "2 x A1-M1";
var time_mont = []; 
var time_cloa = [];

if(str_description.includes("A1")){
time_mont.push (0.62);
} else {
time_mont.push (0);
}
if(str_description.includes("M1")){
time_mont.push (0.6);
} else {
time_mont.push (0);
}
```

How can I manage "2 x " subtring?